# Is Ethereum wallet address case sensitive?

Tags: ether, wallets, addresses

I sent some amount of ETH to a wallet. I checked the wallets balance on ether chain. I entered the address in the search field and noticed both lowercase and uppercase  versions of the address seemed to work.

I wanted to buy a few bucks more, but now I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the address I created. I'd be grateful for some guidance.

Comment: No, it's case insensitive.

Answer (score 88):

Ethereum wallet addresses are in hex [0-9A-F]*. While the address itself is case-insensitive (`A` is the same as `a` to the network), the case sensitivity is used as a (optional) checksum. It was built as an after-thought to an addressing scheme that lacked basic checksum validation.

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/55#issuecomment-187159063

The checksum works like so:

1. lowercase address and remove 0x prefix
2. sha3 hash result from #1
3. change nth letter of address according to the nth letter of the hash:

- 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 → Lowercase
- 8, 9, a, b, c, d, e, f → Uppercase

So, you sha3 hash the address, and look at each Nth character of the sha result. If it's 7 or below, the Nth character in the address is lowercase. If it is 8 or above, that character is uppercase.

(Brought from an old Ethereum forum whose [link is now broken](https://web.archive.org/web/20210220143654/https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/9220/eth-address-upper-and-lower-characters-does-not-matter).)

Comment: And the purpose of a checksum is to help make sure you typed in the address correctly. If there was no case-sensitivity check you could accidentally type "a" instead of "b" and send it to the wrong address. But if you accidentally type "a" instead of "B" (there's a 50% chance the letter was supposed to be capitalized), then you wallet software / exchange would throw an error

Comment: Actually it's more than that. Even if you'd accidentally type "a" instead of "b" in an otherwise checksummed address, an error would be detected, because the capitalization pattern of the *other* letters would now be invalid.

Comment: ^"More than that" (@CherryDT) refers to the probability.  the probability that a user mis-typing an "a" instead of "b" will be detected by this capitalization checksum is greater than 50%.  using an a instead of b will not only change the capitalization of the current character but also the following characters. so the probability to detect the error will be something like (1 - (0.5 * 0.5 * ... _remaining_characters_)), which can be guess-timated to 1 - _very_small_number_ which is high probability; like 99.x %

Answer (score 47):

Capitalization simply means the address has a checksum. You should use the capitalization address because of this, but both will work.

Comment: To verify, any addresses that's fully capitalized can be converted to an checksum address with right capitalization. So in that sense addresses are case insensitive - both addresses are the same. Unlike for example the unix/linux file system where you can have a file named 'Ethereum' and one named 'ethereum' in the same directory. Isn't that right?

Comment: @JorisBontje I think this answer could still be clarified. Changing the letters to upper case doesn't give the address a checksum.

Comment: what does `capitalization address` mean exactly? this answer is a bit ambiguous

Comment: Capitalization tells you whether or not the address is checksummed.  An address with mixed case is checksummed.  An address with any other casing is not checksummed (so, all lower case == not checksummed, all upper-case == not checksummed).  See https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-55.

Answer (score 11):

Look at this examples:

```js
> Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress("0x03fB09251eC05ee9Ca36c98644070B89111D4b3F".toLowerCase());
'0x03FB09251eC05ee9Ca36c98644070B89111D4b3F'
> Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress("0x03fB09251eC05ee9Ca36c98644070B89111D4b3f".toLowerCase());
'0x03FB09251eC05ee9Ca36c98644070B89111D4b3F'
> Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress("0x03fB09251eC05ee9Ca36c98644070B89111D4b3e".toLowerCase());
'0x03Fb09251ec05eE9CA36c98644070B89111D4b3e'
> Web3.utils.isAddress("0x03FB09251eC05ee9Ca36c98644070B89111D4b3f".toLowerCase());
true
> Web3.utils.isAddress("0x03FB09251eC05ee9Ca36c98644070B89111D4b3F".toLowerCase());
true
> Web3.utils.isAddress("0x03FB09251eC05ee9Ca36c98644070B89111D4b3F");
true
> Web3.utils.isAddress("0x03FB09251eC05ee9Ca36c98644070B89111D4b3f");
false
> Web3.utils.isAddress("0x03FB09251eC05ee9Ca36c98644070B89111D4b3e");
false
> Web3.utils.isAddress("0x03FB09251eC05ee9Ca36c98644070B89111D4b3E");
false
```

Note the last char ;)