# How to check for valid contract address using web3?

Tags: web3js, addresses

I am simply trying to avoid the error:

> Error: invalid address

`web3` throws this error when the address to a contract is not valid. 
Is there a way to catch this error ? I am using web3 in a nodejs app.

Comment: Natively: `web3.isAddress([addr])`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is an `isAddress()` method from `web3.utils`, you need to use version one or following version (v1-beta, now default and latest via npm)

Example:

`web3.utils.isAddress(address)`

---

Solidity Docs link: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html?highlight=isValidAddress#isaddress

Answer (score 1):

The formula for creating addresses is detailed in this post:

[How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated)

> Start with the public key (64 bytes)
>
> Take the Keccak-256 hash of the public key. You should now have a string that is 32 bytes. (note: SHA3-256 eventually became the standard, but Ethereum uses Keccak)
>
> Take the last 20 bytes of this public key (Keccak-256). Or, in other words, drop the first 12 bytes. These 20 bytes are the address, or 40 characters. When prefixed with 0x it becomes 42 characters long.

Basically an ethereum address can be any 40 hex alphanumeric character string + a prepend of 0x .

If you are just looking to check that the string you've got follows the ethereum address pattern, you can write a JS script to check that the string conforms to the criteria above.

Comment: I basically want to catch the error: Error: invalid address that web3j thows when you give him a simple string like "hello"

Comment: So you don't want to validate the address you just want to catch the error?

Comment: For now yes, I'll validate it as well but I want to prevent my whole backend to crash in case a wrong address is inputed

Comment: You can use JS' in built try and catch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to test whether the address is valid or not.

```
if(isAddress(address)){
    //code when address is correct
}
else{
    // code to be executed when address is incorrect
}


var isAddress = function (address) {
    // function isAddress(address) {
        if (!/^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$/i.test(address)) {
        // check if it has the basic requirements of an address
        return false;
    } else if (/^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$/.test(address) || /^(0x)?[0-9A-F]{40}$/.test(address)) {
        // If it's all small caps or all all caps, return "true
        return true;
    } else {
        // Otherwise check each case
        return isChecksumAddress(address);
    }
}


var isChecksumAddress = function (address) {
    // Check each case
    address = address.replace('0x','');
    var addressHash = web3.sha3(address.toLowerCase());
    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++ ) {
        // the nth letter should be uppercase if the nth digit of casemap is 1
        if ((parseInt(addressHash[i], 16) > 7 && address[i].toUpperCase() !== address[i]) || (parseInt(addressHash[i], 16) <= 7 && address[i].toLowerCase() !== address[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I guess the source is this: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/55#issuecomment-185938403 - now there is a way of doing it directly in web3 ( even if there is a proposed solution on web3.account as well: https://github.com/web3j/web3j/pull/134/files#diff-db8702981afff54d3de6a913f13b7be4R22 which is referenced in EIP55 comments)