# Is there any way to create an ethereum account from RSA key?

Tags: accounts, parity, cryptography, parity-wallet

I have my very private RSA key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJQQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCSswggknAgEAAoICAQDI0vCkxjyJQ7b7
MVJKKXVTFSH3yN5xWozV1pZ8grTTr6dL90bmeCHIw9PnsZRJWsAhstnSnLm1v7KE
kkNqFi2s+sBf1BSBDZ5onoWE0dtb3R2dG25AsYRj54Sd6rtX9U/2aF ... uNjei
sMA0VQ2av7J60ulAz2AYMHoMrEOznhUpgOM7Op7hR3WE0XFkmL4wmcovboCXTtp8
tMK8EN5Hp4YasJp4Hw9Rc50EluiXMsCuc9Uwr41FZhQQJGtWPGImxoiPU6jJfZUP
yja709eeToSrwU6xoYArh7RnN3Qx
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I use keythereum to generate an ethereum wallet:

```
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('my_private_key_file', 'utf8')
const password = 'myVerySecretPassword'

function generateWallet(privateKey, password){

    const dk = {
        privateKey: Buffer.from(privateKey, 'utf8'),
        salt: crypto.randomBytes(32),
        iv: crypto.randomBytes(16)
    }

    const options = {
        kdf: "pbkdf2",
        cipher: "aes-128-ctr",
        kdfparams: {
            c: 262144,
            dklen: 32,
            prf: "hmac-sha256"
        }
    }

    return keythereum.dump(
        password,
        dk.privateKey,
        dk.salt,
        dk.iv,
        options
    )
}
```

That's what I get back:

```
{
    address: 'c1cfd69deab90015dd456164d058f73abe3b80f4',
    crypto: {...},
    id: 'd94389ec-1e8a-4e95-a386-0a3be0900e13',
    version: 3
}
```

Now I want to start transacting from the address `0xc1cfd69deab90015dd456164d058f73abe3b80f4`. How can I unlock it and set as a desired coinbase? The JSON RPC method `parity_newAccountFromSecret` accepts only hex, no more than 64-character long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, there isn't**. Ethereum uses keys based on [ECDSA (Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) that is really different from [RSA (Rivest, Shamir, Adleman)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)).

See also

[How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated)

[Generating a usable Ethereum wallet and its corresponding keys](https://kobl.one/blog/create-full-ethereum-keypair-and-address/)

[ECDSA: The digital signature algorithm of a better internet](https://blog.cloudflare.com/ecdsa-the-digital-signature-algorithm-of-a-better-internet/)