# cryptography algorithm used in ethereum

Tags: solidity, cryptography

what algorithm does ethereum use to generate public and private key pair. If i have both the keys how can i verify the match of the key in solidity, and how much gas does it cost? is it an expensive operation?

Comment: to know more about how ethereum generate keys. see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated

Comment: I think this answer will help you https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15149/get-public-key-of-msg-sender-in-a-smart-contract/15190#15190