# How to generate an Ethereum address using Web3.js using a string of text or brain wallet?

Tags: wallets, addresses

I want to implement a brain wallet like address generator using web3.js -- I basically have a string of text and want to convert this into an Ethereum address. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a snippet excerpted from ConsenSys's eth-lightwallet to generate the address from a arbitrary private key:

```
KeyStore._computeAddressFromPrivKey = function (privKey) {

  // Create the key pair container
  // `ec` is the secp256k1 utils
  var keyPair = ec.genKeyPair();

  // Set the privKey
  keyPair._importPrivate(privKey, 'hex');

  // Derive the pubKey
  var compact = false;
  var pubKey = keyPair.getPublic(compact, 'hex').slice(2);

  // pubKey -> address
  var pubKeyWordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(pubKey);
  var hash = CryptoJS.SHA3(pubKeyWordArray, { outputLength: 256 });
  var address = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex).slice(24);

  return address;
};
```

I added some comments to facilitate comprehension. Hope this helps:)

Comment: lets say I have the following btc private key: 5KTch7mGRUmg7Ksgx9LyzDcqEBZVJcuogGkSBjtESmkzatbJZ3W  --- How would I generate a corresponding eth address with it? thx.

Comment: I've made a simple repo here: https://github.com/yuanfeiz/simple-eth-addr-generator

Comment: @duckx let me know if any further help is needed:)

Comment: i just tried your small application to generate the ethereum address, but how do you output the ethereum private key? see: http://prntscr.com/fxt30y --- i need the private key as how am i going to send my ether back out? thanks.

Comment: how can i generate ethereum address using privatekey or mnemonic in flutter?

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that `web3` is not intended for Ethereum address generation/management, and that this is usually left to the client (Mist, Metamask, Parity, etc).

**However**, there are some native js solutions that may provide the functionality you're looking for in your use case (mnemonic seed):

- [EthereumJS-Accounts](https://github.com/SilentCicero/ethereumjs-accounts/) (seems deprecated)
- [ConsenSys LightWallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet)

Note that I've used neither of these solutions myself.

**Further reading**:

- [How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated)

Comment: But what library are those applications using to generate an address? I doubt they are writing the Ethereum address generator from scratch. thx.

Comment: From looking into the source a bit, it looks like they use the [bitcore-mnemonic](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-mnemonic) library, and [bitcore-lib](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-lib). Check out the constructor [here](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet/blob/ec359a28e0878fe345c49defff4db832e6f7daf7/lib/keystore.js#L76-L117) for some sample code on how they are generating the wallets.

Comment: Keythereum seems to be well supported for JS!