# How to get my 256bits Public Key on geth

Tags: go-ethereum, keystore, public-key, keymanagement

I created an account on geth by `geth account new`, I can see the address by `geth account list` and this address is derived by using the public key. Is there a way I can check the public key of my account? Maybe from the key store UTC file? When I look at the UTC file

> {"address":"dc49102c51879b374af57d7b076c7ead95d81970","crypto":{"cipher":"aes-128-ctr","ciphertext":"1d153ddbbefc99dbe46ecc302a373993c4e2be3d1074889df833d1a444013896","cipherparams":{"iv":"599c34ace50c08eea138697b81cf35ee"},"kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams":{"dklen":32,"n":262144,"p":1,"r":8,"salt":"253b9c98813b82eac1a165bb94a1bd8d52d9c74d764ae0f052275886d4cac0f2"},"mac":"68210a78ba5c2c2b14ef027e48e16ead7f38dfcf8d10e6d7d97f071be86b317d"},"id":"41931deb-63f0-4925-be7e-04e487e89fce","version":3}

Which is the public key or everything is encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UTC file has the private key encrypted with your password.

To access the private key from the file I've used [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum). Then you can use [elliptic](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic) to derive the public key.

Answer (score -3):

The value corresponding to the key "address" is your public key. In your case, the public key is

> dc49102c51879b374af57d7b076c7ead95d81970

Comment: An address is not the public key. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @LinmaoSong Thanks for clearing that. I had read something similar about bitcoin, but was not aware of the same for Ethereum.