# Brute-forcing private keys

Tags: private-key, cryptography, encryption, yellow-paper

In [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/605f5c/public_key_vulnerable_to_brute_force_in_the_future/df3mton/) post by an Ethereum engineer taken from the [Ethereum wiki](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Accounts,_Addresses,_Public_And_Private_Keys,_And_Tokens#Can_the_private_key_be_brute_forced.3F) about brute-forcing private keys, he writes:

> "Public keys are sized so that, absent a breakthrough in solving the
>   discrete logarithm problem, brute force is impractical for any
>   conceivable amount of computing power. With 2^128 possible
>   combinations, and if we assume a modern computer can compute, say, a
>   billion per second (which is a massive overestimate), it would take a
>   million such computers ~5e15 years to brute force your key. If we
>   assume computing power improves by another million fold, it'd take
>   this massive cluster 'only' about 5 billion years."

However, according to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated) question, a private key is 256 bits long. In this case, why is the quote referring to 2^128 instead of 2^256?

Comment: 2^128 is the size of the brute-force search for collisions on 256 bits due to the birthday paradox. So maybe there is a link. But then you only have to find a collision between 160-bits addresses, so 2^80 operations, which is a lot less...

Comment: My math might be off, but when I changed the number to 2^80 keeping the rest of the parameters the same, it would only take 38 years.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: Not my domain of expertise.

Ethereum uses elliptic curve cryptography (ECC) for security. One can perform naïve brute force testing of a 256 bit key by testing all 2^256 combinations. However, similar to how it's unnecessary to test every number between `2` and `n - 1` to test if `n` is prime (worst-case high-school method is `O(n^0.5)`, but [even better algorithms exist](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-fastest-prime-factorization-algorithm-to-date)), ECC can be broken by solving the relevant elliptic curve discrete log problem more efficiently.

The [best *known* algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography) for solving the elliptic curve discrete log problem operate in worst case `O(n^0.5)`; `(2^256)^0.5` yields `2^128` steps for brute forcing a 256-bit key. Hence, at most `2^128` trials are required to break a 256-bit key used for Ethereum. Note that this is unrelated to the birthday paradox, which pertains to collisions; the fact that both happen to be square root of `n` is pure coincidence.