# Transfer ethereum to bitcoin and vice-versa. How can we do that.?

Tags: ether, myetherwallet

How can I transfer my ethereum to my bitcoin wallet and vice-versa. Is there any way to do that?

I'm using java for the same and just curious to know that. I wanted to implement that in my test project.

Thanks in advance.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcoin wallets and Ethereum wallets are not cross-compatible with each other.

How Ethereum addresses are generated: 
[How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated/3619#3619)

Bitcoin wallet generation:
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50289/how-bitcoin-addresses-are-generated

You could use shapeshift.io to "convert" (exchange) between the two.

Comment: Thanks for responding. can you help me to achieve it using java.?