# Generate Ethereum address from a private key

Tags: ether, private-key, php

My question was first asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086690/generate-ethereum-address-from-a-private-key) but due lack of privileges I couldn't move it here directly.

I am trying to generate an Ethereum address based on a given private key following this "[How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated)" and using this [Keccak-256 Ethereum implementation](https://github.com/particlePaul/keccak256). But it show this error:

```
Warning: openssl_pkey_get_details() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /localweb/getethaddress.php on line 15

openssl_pkey_get_private error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long
openssl_pkey_get_private error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header
openssl_pkey_get_private error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
openssl_pkey_get_private error:10092010:elliptic curve routines:d2i_ECPrivateKey:EC lib
openssl_pkey_get_private error:100DE08E:elliptic curve routines:OLD_EC_PRIV_DECODE:decode error
openssl_pkey_get_private error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long
openssl_pkey_get_private error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header
openssl_pkey_get_private error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
openssl_pkey_get_private error:0907B00D:PEM
```

routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib

My implementation:

```
<?php
    require_once 'keccak256.php';


    // Format the private key as PEM
    $header_private_key = "-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    $footer_private_key = "\n-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----";
    //echo hex2bin("1a63b5c735d66d827f40f7d3a257da777cd7997d48bd5d319c36683c0ad3b1de");
    $eth_private_key = $header_private_key . "1a63b5c735d66d827f40f7d3a257da777cd7997d48bd5d319c36683c0ad3b1de" . $footer_private_key;

    // Load private key from a string
    $private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private($eth_private_key);
    var_dump($private_key);
    while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
        echo "openssl_pkey_get_private " . $msg . "<br />\n";

    // Get the Public key
    $_public_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($private_key)['key'];
    $eth_public_key = openssl_pkey_get_public($_public_key);

    // hash the public key
    $hash_public_key = Keccak256\Keccak256::hash($eth_public_key, 256);; 
    $eth_address = '0x' . substr($hash_public_key, -40);


    echo 'Your generated address: ' . $eth_address . '<br>';
    echo 'Myetherwallet address: 0x47180b59dd8c81f46186900bbd29cbf675b3fbd9';


    /*
        a generated address from Myetherwallet 40: 47180b59dd8c81f46186900bbd29cbf675b3fbd9
        private key 64: 1a63b5c735d66d827f40f7d3a257da777cd7997d48bd5d319c36683c0ad3b1de
    */
?>
```

Comment: Here's how they do in the terminal, Using OpenSSL and keccak-256sum from a terminal: https://kobl.one/blog/create-full-ethereum-keypair-and-address/

Comment: @MSwezey I read that article too, but I am confused why the private key provided by Myetherwallet not the same length vs the generated by OpenSSL?

Comment: @HAßdøµ It appears you are trying to wrap the raw private key in a certificate. The internal format used by PEM certificates can be quite complex. I suggest to search a library to do this in PHP, I only know of this js library does the correct encoding https://github.com/blockstack/key-encoder-js

Comment: @Ismael Is is possible at least to convert it using OpenSSL?

Comment: @HAßdøµ Sorry, but I don't known about OpenSSL enough to answer that, you probably want to ask that question in StackOverflow.

Comment: @Ismael I putted a question there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101258/how-to-convert-an-ecdsa-key-to-pem-format

Comment: You might consider using https://github.com/kornrunner/php-keccak. It is working. 
The one you use says "DO NOT USE" in capital letters :)

Comment: I played around with OpenSSL too, as it sounded promising for ecVerify, but I never got a Ethereum key in/out from PEM format.

Answer (score 0):

There are some functions in web3p toolset, but I have no Idea if it will work.

https://github.com/web3p/ethereum-util/blob/0815348c3513e004d7dfa65ebeb31cda9d41f77e/src/Util.php#L133-L172