# Problem with understanding web3.eth.accounts.create()

Tags: web3js

I am trying to use this function in order to create keypairs for users via frontend, and these pairs are associated with username and password.

However, I noticed, that this:

```
var account = new Web3EthAccounts('ws://localhost:8545');

console.log(account.create());
```

works always, **no matter if on that port something is running or not**. And for that reason I am not so sure anymore, if the `web3.eth.accounts-library` is even interacting with my running blockchain. I also am not even sure anymore if thats even necessary, or if the keypair just doesn't need that connection.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the `create` function, it's simply generating a string of random bytes.

```
// web3-eth-accounts
Accounts.prototype.create = function create(entropy) {
    return this._addAccountFunctions(Account.create(entropy || utils.randomHex(32)));
};

// eth-lib/lib/account
var create = function create(entropy) {
  var innerHex = keccak256(Bytes.concat(Bytes.random(32), entropy || Bytes.random(32)));
  var middleHex = Bytes.concat(Bytes.concat(Bytes.random(32), innerHex), Bytes.random(32));
  var outerHex = keccak256(middleHex);
  return fromPrivate(outerHex);
};
```

It's kind of like if every atom in the universe was a private key you can use, and you're simply picking a random one. The chances of someone randomly picking the same one is close to 0%.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to be connected to anything to generate a key pair. It's essentially just generating a random number.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here above, the private key is generated completely randomly, without checking for a "collision" with any other key online.

However, A public ethereum address has 160 bits (derived by a hash of a longer key).
Therefore the odds of generating a double address in a certain attempt is 1 to 2^160, which is very, very close to 0%.

Here is a detailed explanation i found on why there are around 10 addresses for every cubic micrometer of the sun :)

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/57uqbn/if_creating_an_account_consumes_gas_how_is_it/d8v8jnb/

for more info on how those keys are generated you can look here:

[How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated)