# How do I get ETH into my testnet Metamask wallet?

Tags: truffle, metamask

After switching to testnet from the dropdown in Metamask, the address used is still my Mainnet address.

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(a,b) {
      Merchant.accounts = b;
      console.log("Merchant accounts: " + Merchant.accounts);
      let x = web3.eth.getBalance;
      console.log(x);
    });
```

shows `0xc27a6adac593d1c02355f307ea92f6261269566d`, my mainnet address.

I've tried sending funds via truffle console:

```
truffle(development)> ma
'0xc27a6adac593d1c02355f307ea92f6261269566d'
truffle(development)> web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: web3.eth.accounts[1], to: ma, value: 10000000000000})
'0x9c59733f9e8bed3f13d6f96589894239a43af6a5e387b40e7a9fad4e0157aaa7'
```

I don't see the balance change in MetaMask.

How do I add funds to my test Metamask?

Comment: Assuming both MetaMask and Truffle are speaking to the same test network, I would expect what you're doing to work. (You could also just import the private key of the account you already have into MetaMask.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there is not such thing as a **"mainnet address"**. All addresses are just private keys, which [mathematically transformed](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated/3619#3619) into ethereum addresses.

Which means you can use the same addresses on any network. But Metamask will just show you the **funds your address has on the current active network**.

In order to see your founds, make sure Metamask points to the same network.

E.g: if you are using Ganache (previously test-rpc) make sure you Metamask points to the right network to see the founds:

[image]

You may use **truffle console** to send founds from your (unlocked) addresses to any other address on the same network.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
 from:web3.eth.coinbase,
 to: '0xaEC98826319EF42aAB9530A23306d5a9b113E23D',
 value: web3.toWei(10, "ether")
})
```

Comment: You may also import your Ganache account into Metamask by
`Account-->import-->Private Key`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which testnet you're working on, you can get ether from testnet faucets. This is a working Rinkeby faucet, which I've used in the past: https://www.rinkeby.io/#faucet and a working Ropsten faucet: http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/

You might also consider resetting MetaMask’s state:

- Make sure you have your seed phrase backed up.
- Lock MetaMask (in the top right menu)
- Click “Forgot my Password (import)”
- Enter your seed phrase.
- You should be able to submit transactions again.

These steps are taken directly from https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/USERS.md

Answer (score 0):

This is also a simple and useful [MetaMask faucet](https://faucet.metamask.io/) for Ropsten.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purpose, I am using `ganache-cli` and I get eth into my wallet with the following code. It is `web3.py` but it is easy to transpose into `web3.js`.

```
def add_ether(address, amount):
    ''' Add ether to a wallet. This is only for testing purpose. Of course, this does not work on mainnet.

    >>> a = w3.eth.account.create('test')
    >>> add_ether(a.address, 10)
    >>> w3.eth.getBalance(a.address)
    10'''

    sender = w3.eth.coinbase
    if amount > w3.eth.getBalance(sender):
        raise ValueError("The sender does not have enough coins.")
    w3.eth.sendTransaction({'from': sender,
                              'to': address,
                              'value': amount})
```