# How to know, if a particular ethereum address exist?

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to know if a particular ethereum address exist or not. Is there any way using web3.js

Comment: Hi there. All addresses exist. Do you mean is there a way to know if someone owns a private key that maps to a particular address?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, addresses are the hash result of a public key.

You question is somewhat a duplicate of [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated) , which already been answered.

The answer provided in the linked post should give you the keys on how to compute the elements in order to check if an address is valid.

[Another article that might help you](https://medium.com/@zanewithspoon/how-is-an-ethereum-address-generated-9f08e6f83f77)