# How to figure out if an account address exists or not

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am trying to create a user database with solidity and ethereum blockchain.

i have a super user who needs to add other users using their address as a unique identifier. The address is not passed through `msg.sender` so how can i know if it really exists or not? ?

Comment: What is meant by Super user? In Eth?

Comment: Super user is just a type that i invented to say that the account calling the adduser method is different from the one that i am trying to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [linked question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37210/how-to-know-if-a-particular-ethereum-address-exist) all addresses exist.

If you want to know if for a given address a private key exists (e.g. this address can send transactions) you can have the method `register()` which is supposed to be called by normal users. This method will store `msg.sender` to the `registeredAddresses` mapping.

Another method `approve(address addr)` is supposed to be called by the super user and it will put the address to `approvedAddresses` mapping, after checking the `addr` exists in the `registeredAddresses` mapping. The fact that this address is in `registeredAddresses` means that someone must own the private key for this address.

This of course imposes the gas cost that users will need to pay for calling `register()`. Instead you can also do it off-chain, just ask the address that you need to add to the database to sign some random message with their private key then check it against the address with `ecrecover`.

Comment: So, from what i understand from your answer is that, calling register() on an address( e.g. can send transactions ) will prove by the the returned value of the method register() that this address is genuin or not, right ?

Comment: So, from what i understand from your answer is that, i can't really know wether some address has a private key behind untill it actually calls a method from my contract. so what you stated is just a workaround. Thank you, i am implementing it.

Comment: "can't really know wether some address has a private key behind untill it actually calls a method from my contract." yes that's correct. The workaround is to require users to send you a signed message off-chain. You can then verify the signature on-chain when registering users. This way all registered users in your smart contract are guaranteed to have private keys and there needs to be only a single transaction instead of 2.