# Signed message offline does not match public key

Tags: web3js, recovery

I'm trying to sign message with private key offline to prove private key ownership.

The issue is that when validating signed object public key from private address does not match output from recover function.

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8546");

var address = '0x2394d939C761cC9bD6137B82bB9e017657509Afb',
    privateKey = '6ac2663692506980c50e239c300f2fefdac6bc95b0e9bdf8a9bd3f615c1ca726';

var signedObject = web3.eth.accounts.sign('Some data', privateKey);
console.log('Public key matches:', address == web3.eth.accounts.recover(signedObject));
```

This returns false. What am I missing?

Comment: Public key in your question is actually an address. And `web3.eth.accounts.recover` returns the address used to sign the data.

Comment: Try adding `0x` to your private key.

Comment: yes, the 0x did the trick. any reason behind this?

Comment: Because the private key: " is 64 hexadecimal characters. Every single string of 64 hex are, hypothetically, an Ethereum private key" [Source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3619/9938). This is just how you should use hex values, I guess.