# What the difference between Bitcoin and Ethereum private/public keys and address?

Tags: web3js, private-key, bitcoin, encryption, public-key

I am trying to find a library for creating Ethereum wallets in a web environment (PHP, JS). I found Keytheremjs lib, but if use it in a browser, this tool is very slow. But I found a lot of simple PHP libs for generating keys for a Bitcoin.

**Questions:**

- What is the difference in encrypting Bitcoin and Ethereum private/public
  keys and address?
- Can I use Bitcoin keys for the Ethereum?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes and no.

- No - a Bitcoin address cannot be directly used in Ethereum, and vice versa.
- Yes - underneath, a bitcoin private key is essentially a random 256-bit number (in a certain range, see [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key)). And the private key's corresponding public key is essentially the x and y coordinates of a point on an elliptic curve. Bitcoin and Ethereum both use the same elliptic curve (secp256k1), thus the same private/public key pair can be used in both Bitcoin and Ethereum. However, the steps for converting a public key to an address are different for [Bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address) and [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated).

Answer (score 13):

Just to add to the very good accepted answer:

```
Coin     | Address size        | Address encoding | Address creation
---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------ 
Bitcoin  | 160 bits (20 bytes) | Base58Check      | RIPEMD160(SHA256(<public_key>)
Ethereum | 160 bits (20 bytes) | HEX*             | KECCAK256(<public_key>)**
```

- *Optional [EIP-55](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md) checksum.
- **Use the last 20 bytes.