# Web3j - what is <ensName> when using existing contract

Tags: blockchain, web3j, java

I was just beginning my blockchain development by following https://docs.web3j.io/getting_started.html , I saw some `0x<address>|<ensName>`, what is the address and ensName consecutively in the following piece of code and how do I get them ? also how do I format these number, do I need to include the pipeline ? (ex : `0x921uiwojo|<ensName>`)

Code :

```
YourSmartContract contract = YourSmartContract.load(
        "0x<address>|<ensName>", <web3j>, <credentials>, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the address and ensName consecutively in the following piece of code and how do I get them ?

The address is the address that your contract - or the contract you want to interact with - has previously been deployed at in the blockchain. The ENS name is an alternative way to refer to a specific address, but it can only be used if it's been set up. Not all addresses have ENS names.

> also how do I format these number,

The format of an address is `0x` followed by 40 HEX characters (20 bytes). See [How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated)

The format of ENS name is any alphanumeric string of seven characters or more. (Having said that, I *think* any characters are allowed, it's just there might be difficulties resolving them. See ["What about foreign characters? What about upper case letters? Is any unicode character valid?"](https://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/faq.html#what-about-foreign-characters-what-about-upper-case-letters-is-any-unicode-character-valid) in the FAQ.) See the [ENS documentation](https://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/) to understand what it's all about.

> do I need to include the pipeline

It's not a pipe, it's an "or", in the documentation sense. "Either use a raw address ***or*** an ENS name."

Also note that the contents of `<` and `>` (including those two characters) should be replaced with actual values...

Comment: I see , so once we create a contract, we will automatically generate this contract address / ENS ?

Comment: Do you have any snippet code using Web3j that I can use to get the Ensname passing the address as a Param?