# How to generates the private and public key from a given name or address?

Tags: transactions, private-blockchain, private-key, public-key

I want to generate both keys for transaction and also let me know how to calculate the processing time using solidity for the whole program?

Comment: You want to generate the private key for any given address??? Well who doesn't...

Comment: Yes i want to generate the both keys from the given address and calculate the processing time

Answer (score 0):

The address is 20-byte hexadecimal string that is being generated by taking Keccak-256 hash of the public key. but the reverse is not possible.
 for more info check below link 
http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/glossary.html, 
[How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated/3619#3619)