# Is there a particular reason as to why evm adresses are only 160 bits and not 256 bits?

Tags: evm, addresses, data

Is there a particular reason as to why evm adresses are only 160 bits and not 256 bits?
Wouldn't that create a pigeon hole problem eventually? Is this solely to save 96 per addresses so to decrease blocksize?
But would there eventually be ways to expand those spaces while keeping backwards compatibility? I feel like truncation would limit us from padding old addresses with zeros?
I know that both address space and key spaces are unimaginably large, but at some point, with the exponential growth of the network, wouldn't those limits still eventually be reached?

Comment: See https://ethereum-magicians.org/t/increasing-address-size-from-20-to-32-bytes/5485

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56057/why-are-the-last-20-bytes-of-the-public-key-used-as-the-address#:~:text=Taking%20the%20last%2020%20bytes,Pre%2Dempting%20security%20mechanism.