# how can ethereum addresses are same between different networks (testnet & Main)?

Tags: blockchain, ether, wallets, metamask, myetherwallet

I found, Wallet address are remain interchangeable if i switched between the different networks(Main Network , Ropsen Network & Rinkeby Network)

is it assigned to particular machine IP, if not then how can process identified between testnetwork or main metwork ??

how addresses are work internally in blockchain?

Currently, I am using Metamask wallet for the same.

Please help us to get rid of this confusion, share the links for the same which you find more effective for me.

Comment: an address is just a number, that simple. see addresses as nicknames, for example , your nickname is "user1986760" , you can use it in ethereum.stackexchange, or in electronics.stackexchange, and it is going to be the same wherever you use it

Comment: yes agree, address work as identifier, but confusion how it works internally, is it assigned to particular MAC address of System, i mean how is it same for every network (test or Main). how system differentiate - is this transaction belong to Main or test ??

Comment: it is not a networking address, it is just a key in key-value database. Every node in ethereum network has a copy of this database and every time you send some amount to unknown address it is added to this database and then this database is shared among nodes again.

Comment: the networks are differenciated by a field called `chainID` , it is unique per network

Answer (score 4):

The same private key will give the same public key and address in whichever network. It's a deterministic process and it does not depend on the used network. This is actually even helpful in some situations - for example if you accidentally send Ether to wrong network's address, you can just create the same account in the other network to claim your Ethers.

You can find more details about public key and address generation for example here: [How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated)