# web3.py manually derive address from public key string [for dummies]

Tags: addresses, web3.py, public-key

Let's say I need to derive the address from a public key string.
`0xbb8250cc01a0afa7dcaee987b2adda8d1b0a0bb2f7cc427bd942a98c7837364d62e6ea4728a99db39fd55a6f7474a159ca88a96b40279044a1349a2280c8cd43`

According to [this reply here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated/3619) I need to:

1. hash it: 
   I used [this online hash generator](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) because the built in `Web3.sha3()` function doesn't seem to return the same value for some reason and I don't know how to specify the input for the `soliditySha3()` function.

So the hash is now:

`>>> hash = a591d48139d1f97e701cc15cb42a35c0ba7abf1aa44cfc82cdba0033779719eb`

2. Cut the first 20 characters and add `0x` prefix:

`hash = "0x" + hash[24:]
=> 0xb42a35c0ba7abf1aa44cfc82cdba0033779719eb`

Unfortunately this is not the correct address. The address should be `0xD4aD2c314d60089654bf292874AC0488F3ee77bA`

So what's the correct way for dummies to derive the address from a public key string?

Comment: Make sure you are hashing the bytes, not the hex as a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look here: [Mastering Ethereum - Keys and Addresses](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/04keys-addresses.asciidoc#which-hash-function-am-i-using). This chapter walks step by step through the process for deriving the public key.

I think the main issue is that the online encoder is not expecting a hex input. Try using web3.js which seems to work perfectly:

```
key = "0xbb8250cc01a0afa7dcaee987b2adda8d1b0a0bb2f7cc427bd942a98c7837364d62e6ea4728a99db39fd55a6f7474a159ca88a96b40279044a1349a2280c8cd43"
```

> "0xbb8250cc01a0afa7dcaee987b2adda8d1b0a0bb2f7cc427bd942a98c7837364d62e6ea4728a99db39fd55a6f7474a159ca88a96b40279044a1349a2280c8cd43"

```
hash = web3.utils.keccak256(key)
```

> "0x31e2c58dcae613b45af300b1d4ad2c314d60089654bf292874ac0488f3ee77ba"

```
address = "0x" + hash.slice(24+2)
```

> "0xd4ad2c314d60089654bf292874ac0488f3ee77ba"

EDIT: Web3.py works the same for me too

```
>>> key = "0xbb8250cc01a0afa7dcaee987b2adda8d1b0a0bb2f7cc427bd942a98c7837364d62e6ea4728a99db39fd55a6f7474a159ca88a96b40279044a1349a2280c8cd43"
>>> hash = Web3.sha3(hexstr=key)
>>> address = Web3.toHex(hash[-20:])
>>> address
```

> '0xd4ad2c314d60089654bf292874ac0488f3ee77ba'

Comment: broken link, typcial for eth

Comment: @qrtLs i have fixed the link