# Programmatically getting an Ethereum address for a raw hex private key

Tags: web3js, private-key

Let's assume one has a private key in a raw hexadecimal format:

```
# Not a real key
ddc64840388bc5f2bc9d40a29b35ae3c41a8cdf9ee1dfdc5a46414e3db3de2db
```

How one would get the corresponding Ethereum account from a UNIX command line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated)

Comment: @Ismael It does not answer. This question is specifically about easily callable APIs. I am not interested in math behind it.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa that is not clear from your question, if you are looking for easily callable APIs (e.g. web3.js / ethers.js) then your question should state that.

Comment: @SCBuergel.eth Thank you. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option #1:

```
const util = require("ethereumjs-util");
const address = "0x" + util.privateToAddress(privateKey).toString("hex");
```

Option #2:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3();
const address = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey).address;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to get it with web3.js and [Node REPL](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-node-js-repl).

Assuming you know how to set up a Node environment and install `eth-lib` package. This package is currently being used as a dependency for web3.js functions.

Open node:

```sh
node
```

Then start the multi-line editor with the command

```
.editor
```

And paste in and edit the code:

```
const privateKey = 'ddc64840388bc5f2bc9d40a29b35ae3c41a8cdf9ee1dfdc5a46414e3db3de2db';
const { Account } = require('eth-lib/lib');
// Note it is very important we add a 0x prefix here,
// as the fromPrivate() accepts anything for the input
// and does very little safety checks for the incoming input
const account = Account.fromPrivate('0x' + privateKey);
console.log("Account for", privateKey, "is", account.address);
```

This will output:

```
Account for ddc64840388bc5f2bc9d40a29b35ae3c41a8cdf9ee1dfdc5a46414e3db3de2db is 0x010335E6E38AeACA85DaeeA22F291f86E64d1DaB
```