# Different kind of Wallet/Addresses/Accounts

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, bitcoin

I have a few questions regarding crypto wallet accounts and currencies.

Recently I came across *https://www.bitaddress.org/*. This website generates bitcoin wallets. Now, when I tried to verify that account created by this website, I searched for a bitcoin address validator and in that, I used that address given by that website and it worked.

Just out of curiosity, I went to *https://etherscan.io* and tried to check that address but it didn't work.

I want to know

1. Are Bitcoin wallet and Ethereum wallet are created differently? if yes, What is the process?
2. Using a bitcoin wallet, can I receive Ethereum ... or other cryptocurrencies?
3. Is there something all a common wallet generator that can work with all kind of cryptocurrencies.
4. Can anyone explain the process involved in creating Ethereum wallet and Bitcoin wallet.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, they use a different algorithms to generate addresses.
2. No, you cannot use a bitcoin address to receive ethers, or any other cryptocurrency.
3. Yes, there are ["Hierarchical Deterministic Wallets"](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki).
4. For Ethereum see this: [How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated)