# Are Ethereum Addresses the same as Polygon?

Tags: ether, addresses, polygon, opensea

On OpenSea, I can sell my NFTs on Polygon (MATIC) to lower gas fees. Whenever the NFT is resold, I can specify a royalty to be received by certain wallets. When I create a collection, it prompts me for address(es) to send the royalties to.

[image]

Do I specify an ETH address in the "payout wallet address" field? Is that compatible with ETH on Polygon? The real ETH address (not the sample I provided in the image) corresponds to a Metamask wallet.

Comment: Hello, this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/107761/same-address-in-different-blockchains-does-that-mean-the-same-person-entity/107763#107763 should answer your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be MATIC is an ERC20 token so the address should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you withdrew MATIC and sent it to your Etherum address instead of Polygon wallet. This is a common mistake as Polygon is a layer 2 solution built on ETH. Do not fear, you only need to find a way to add the MATIC contract address to your ETH wallet to see your MATIC balance. Being that MATIC is a chain built on top of Ethereum essentially your transfer is safe and your funds were received by your ETH wallet.