# Getting the wrong address back from ecrecover

Tags: addresses, signature, cryptography, ethereumjs, ecrecover

When I sign a string using the following code I get back a different address to the one I signed with. The address returned is different for different strings.

```
const util = require('ethereumjs-util')
const msg = web3.sha3('hello!');
const sig = web3.eth.sign(web3.eth.accounts[0], msg);
const {v, r, s} = util.fromRpcSig(sig);

const pubKey  = util.ecrecover(util.toBuffer(msg), v, r, s);
const addrBuf = util.pubToAddress(pubKey);
const addr    = util.bufferToHex(addrBuf);
```

I took the code from the answer to a question I asked previously here [Getting an address from ethereumjs-utils erecover](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12571).

I asked a question here: [Secp256k1 bindings are not compiled. Pure JS implementation will be used](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12820) about a possibly relevant error. The comments suggested that it should be harmless though.

Comment: Can you please post exact versions of the packages you use (`npm list`). I think there were a bug in some of the `testrpc` dependencies.

Comment: @maxtaldykin https://pastebin.com/v2ydwkgy this is what I got

Comment: @maxtaldykin I am using macOS sierra version 10.12.4 not sure where to find the testrpc version

Comment: @maxtaldykin I got an error http://imgur.com/a/JTyU4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Geth adds prefix to the message before siginig it in `web3.eth.sign` (see [JSON-PRC spec](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sign)). 
Without this it can be possible to trick user to sign transaction (more [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3731#issuecomment-283620075)).

So, the correct code to sign message with `web3.eth.sign` and recover address with `ethereumjs-util.ecrecover` or (Solidity's `ecrecover`) should add the prefix explicitly.

```
const util = require('ethereumjs-util')

const msg = new Buffer('hello');
const sig = web3.eth.sign(web3.eth.accounts[0], '0x' + msg.toString('hex'));
const res = util.fromRpcSig(sig);

const prefix = new Buffer("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n");
const prefixedMsg = util.sha3(
  Buffer.concat([prefix, new Buffer(String(msg.length)), msg])
);

const pubKey  = util.ecrecover(prefixedMsg, res.v, res.r, res.s);
const addrBuf = util.pubToAddress(pubKey);
const addr    = util.bufferToHex(addrBuf);

console.log(web3.eth.accounts[0],  addr);
```

---

There is misleading inconsistency with `ethereumjs-testrpc` as it does not prefix message before signing it in `web3.eth.sign`.

Comment: It seems meteor will only allow node versions of 4.x

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much I've been struggling with this for ages

Comment: sorry just a small thing... the ecrecover address is all lower case but the original address has some caps. Does this make a difference?

Comment: never mind its answered here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2045/is-ethereum-wallet-address-case-sensitive

Comment: How on earth did you find this?!  I've been looking forever.