# Signature generated through web3.eth.sign not leading to same address after fromRpcSig

Tags: solidity, metamask, ethereumjs, ganache

I am trying to write sign a challenge using web3.eth.sign, web3 uses ganache.provider(),
But when i do fromRpcSig(signature) ecrecover(challenge) which results in different address. But when i sign using metamask web3 every thing works fine. I am writing test suit for signin using ganache-cli. Thanks in advance

//front end code using metamask injected web3
`web3.eth.sign(web3.eth.defaultAccount, web3.sha3(challenge), async (err, signature) => { Here i will send signature to backend })`

//Backend code
`const eutil = require('ethereumjs-util');
const sig = eutil.fromRpcSig(signature);
const publicKey = eutil.ecrecover(eutil.sha3(challenge), sig.v, sig.r, sig.s);
const address = eutil.pubToAddress(publicKey).toString('hex');`

// Test suit
same as front end but using ganache provider

Url for full code
https://github.com/pramodramdas/digital_healthcare
**front end code**: src->components->login.js->login()
**back end code**: routes->auth-routes.js
**test suit**: tests->check_flow.test.js->test case('Check Signin')

**test case is not working with current implementation, but metamask implementation works as expected**

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Vindberg i have tried method provided in here (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/getting-the-wrong-address-back-from-ecrecover/12684#12684) and seems to be working in test suit, but i need to check in actual application when using metamask, I will confirm once i have checked with metamask

Comment: @smarx Please find the code which i had earlier,  
web3.eth.sign(account, web3.eth.sha3(challenge), (err, signature)=>{})  

const eutil = require('ethereumjs-util');  
const sig = eutil.fromRpcSig(signature);  
const publicKey = eutil.ecrecover(eutil.sha3(challenge), sig.v, sig.r, sig.s);  
const address = eutil.pubToAddress(publicKey).toString('hex');  
if(('0x'+address) === client_address)

Comment: Now my metamask implementation is broken. I reverted back to my old code and have tried installing different version of web3 ie.0.20.3 same as metamasks web3 version. but still no use, test case not working.

Comment: Hi Pram, please add your code to the original question. It seems that Metamask doesn't prefix the transaction with "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32"?

Comment: @Vindberg i have added code.

Comment: I use Web3Js for my automated tests, sorry cant help with the ethereumjs lib.