# Getting incorrect signer address on verifying the signature with the generated hash of the signed message in solidity

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, javascript, signature, keccak

Basically on verifying the signature with the generated hash of the signed message, I'm getting the correct signer on JS, but not on Solidity.

**JS Code (According to *Keir Finlow-Bates'* suggestion)**:

```
async function signHello() {
    // Encode parameters
    const encodedParams = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
        ['string'],
        ['hello']
    );

    const hash = ethers.utils.hexlify(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(encodedParams));

    const prefixedHash = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(
        ['string', 'bytes'],
        ['\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n' + hash.length, hash]
    );

    console.log("Hash: ", prefixedHash)

    // Sign the message
    const signature = await wallet.signMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(prefixedHash));
    
    console.log("Signature:", signature);

    return {'hash': prefixedHash, 'signature': signature}

}

function getSigner(hash, signature) {

    const digest = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.solidityPack(['string', 'bytes32'], ["\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash]));
    return ethers.utils.recoverAddress(digest, signature);
}

signHello().then((res) => {
    console.log(getSigner(res.hash, res.signature))  // getting the correct signer address here
})
```

**JS Code:**

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/YOUR_ALCHEMY_API_KEY");
const privateKey = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY";
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

async function signHello() {
    // Encode parameters
    const encodedParams = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
        ['string'],
        ['hello']
    );

    let hash = ethers.utils.keccak256(encodedParams);

    console.log("Hash: ", hash)
    
    // Sign the message
    const signature = await wallet.signMessage(hash);

    console.log("Signature:", signature);

    return {'hash': hash, 'signature': signature}

}


function getSigner(hash, signature) {

    return ethers.utils.verifyMessage(hash, signature)

    // Using the code below, getting the same incorrect signer address as getting from the getSigner() solidity function

    // const digest = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.solidityPack(['string', 'bytes32'], ["\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash]));
    // return ethers.utils.recoverAddress(digest, signature);
}

signHello().then((res) => {
    console.log(getSigner(res.hash, res.signature))  // getting the correct signer address here
})
```

**Solidity Code:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";

contract Signer {
    
    function getHash() public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                "hello"
            )
        );
    }
    
    function getSigner(bytes32 _hash, bytes memory _signature)
        public
        pure
        returns (address)
    {
        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;
        uint8 v;
        if (_signature.length != 65) {
            return address(0);
        }
        assembly {
            r := mload(add(_signature, 32))
            s := mload(add(_signature, 64))
            v := byte(0, mload(add(_signature, 96)))
        }
        if (v < 27) {
            v += 27;
        }
        if (v != 27 && v != 28) {
            return address(0);
        } else {
            return
                ecrecover(
                    keccak256(
                        abi.encodePacked(
                            "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32",
                            _hash
                        )
                    ),
                    v,
                    r,
                    s
                );

        }
    }

    function getSignerUsingOpenzeppelin(bytes32 _hash, bytes memory _signature)
        public
        pure
        returns (address)
    {

        return ECDSA.recover(_hash, _signature);

    }

}
```

PS, I'm getting the same hash for **hello** in both **JS** as well as **Solidity** codes, i.e., `0x984002fcc0ca639f96622add24c2edd2fe72c65e71ca3faa243e091e0bc7cdab`.

Using the **JS Code (According to *Keir Finlow-Bates'* suggestion)**, getting this hash:

`0xd9f807e25c27377c0d87443b1736dfaa5c3a582d7023b696acf4dde098ee659e`

Which is when used with the corresponding generated signature, returning the correct/expected signer.

But, now the question is how to generate the same hash in solidity?

As `keccak256(abi.encode("hello"))` is returning a different hash i.e., `0x984002fcc0ca639f96622add24c2edd2fe72c65e71ca3faa243e091e0bc7cdab`.

Comment: why are you implementing it by yourself? is it no better to use Openzeppelin contracts for this https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/5.x/api/utils#ECDSA

Comment: @MajdT, I'm getting the incorrect signer even when using the **Openzeppelin's ECDSA library**, like this:  

`return ECDSA.recover(_hash, _signature);`

Comment: @MajdTL, Thanks for responding. I've added the function in the contract to get the signer using Openzeppelin's library too. It's returning a different signer, but still not the correct/expected one.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/getting-the-wrong-address-back-from-ecrecover/12684

Usually people complain they're not recovering the right signature because they're not adding the signed message prefix. You either have to do it explicitly, or use both signing and recovery functions that do it for you. I suspect you're mixing them up here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @KeirFinlow-Bates. I've edited the JS code by adding the signed message prefix as per your suggestion. But now, the generated hash is different from what's being generated in solidity, so how to generate the same hash in solidity as well ?

Comment: ethers library appends "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32" prefix when ethers.utils.signMessage() is called, so while hash generation you can exclude that.

Comment: @Nikhil, thanks for responding. After excluding that, I'm getting a different hash i.e., `0xbd4e3e4488312fbdbebf9d859581be67532efbb0152c94e698f9829aa83b4a3f`, but still **how to get the same hash using solidity**, that's where I'm stuck now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to sign the message hash in JS is to `arrayify` it first, using `ethers.utils.arrayify`, so the **signHello()** and **getSigner()** functions can be rewritten like this:

```
async function signHello() {
    // Encode parameters
    const encodedParams = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
        ['string'],
        ['hello']
    );

    let hash = ethers.utils.keccak256(encodedParams);

    console.log("Hash: ", hash)

    // Sign the message hash after arrayifying
    const signature = await wallet.signMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(hash));
    
    console.log("Signature:", signature);

    return {'hash': hash, 'signature': signature}

}

function getSigner(hash, signature) {

    // Verify the arrayifyed message hash with the signature to get the signer

    return ethers.utils.verifyMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(hash), signature)

}
```

So, now the generated hash is exactly identical in both JS and Solidity, also the signature can be verified in both, returning the correct/expected signer.