# Case - does it make sense?

Tags: addresses, encoding

Am I right, that `0xc1384BAFDD139a61998e1f612948da22fD878BD2` and `0xc1384bafdd139a61998e1f612948da22fd878bd2` are the same addresses?

I'm asking, because, for example, in Bitcoin `base64` is used, so uppercase and lowercase are not the same.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2045/is-ethereum-wallet-address-case-sensitive