# eth_requestAccounts returns an address with all lowercase?

Tags: metamask

Why does metamask return the address in lowercase?
Is there any rationale behind this.

Shouldn't it return the address with no modification?

Comment: idk what the reason is but better always to convert the address to Checksum when you get it from metamask or user or contract

Comment: Regarding the second part of the question please check [the answer.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/19048/92964)